# react-three-fiber "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" when loading gltf mesh and animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, jsx, react-three-fiber

I have searched the forums, and am unable to understand why my .js file is returning this error:

```js
react-reconciler.development.js:5931 
        
       Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {isBufferGeometry, uuid, name, type, index, attributes, morphAttributes, morphTargetsRelative, groups, boundingBox, boundingSphere, drawRange, userData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-reconciler.development.js:5931:9)
    at createChild (react-reconciler.development.js:6185:7)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-reconciler.development.js:6457:25)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-reconciler.development.js:6877:16)
    at reconcileChildren (react-reconciler.development.js:11398:28)
    at updateHostComponent$1 (react-reconciler.development.js:12147:3)
    at beginWork (react-reconciler.development.js:13862:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-reconciler.development.js:14219:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-reconciler.development.js:14268:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-reconciler.development.js:14329:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-reconciler.development.js:19537:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-reconciler.development.js:18686:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-reconciler.development.js:18597:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-reconciler.development.js:18565:7)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-reconciler.development.js:17836:74)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:34)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:239:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:533:21)
```

I am attempting to load a gltf mesh into my react-three-fiber scene and include a react scale event. I successfully loaded the gltf, however I am getting tripped up by the JSX syntax when I try to incorporate it with properties I've defined.

Here is my code:

```js
function foobut(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/foobut.glb")
  const myMesh = React.useRef();
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
      <mesh
      scale={active ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
      ref={myMesh}
      >
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        geometry={nodes.Circle.geometry}
        material={nodes.Circle.material}
        scale={0.50}
        position={[0, 0, 0]}
        material-metalness={4.6}
       </ mesh>
  );
}
```

EDIT: The issue disappears when I nest everything in "<mesh ... />". However, I do not believe this is the correct method, as the animations do not work--it is stuck on one frame. Furthermore, this contradicts practices I've seen in other works (e.g., https://codesandbox.io/s/rrppl0y8l4?file=/src/App.js:584-594 -- notice what is nested in the mesh [image: example of mesh nesting]).

Comment: The first obvious thing I see is that your mesh component isn't formatted properly you have options in the body of the component

Comment: @b.stevens.photo I'm a bit confused. This is how it is formatted in several examples I've used (e.g., https://codesandbox.io/s/interaction-98ppy?file=/src/App.js:363-447 ). When I close with </ mesh> after ref, none of the attributes are considered!

Comment: Without the events, I am able to wrap the attributes in "<mesh ... />" without issue.

Comment: I have tried nesting everything in <mesh as well, the error disappears...but the animations don't work!